# Can not register the new task to remote servers with PS4

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to register the new task to the remote servers.
However I mentioned the error at `-Trigger` option in `Register-ScheduledTask` command.

code

```
$tasks = @(("script1", "args1", "04:00:00", "name1"), ("script2", "args2", "04:30:00", "name2"))

$c = New-CimSession -ComputerName "hostname" -Credential "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

foreach($task in $tasks) {

    #setting action
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -CimSession $c -Execute $task[0] -Argument $task[1] -WorkingDirectory "C:\unyo\script\"

    #setting trigger
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -at $task[2]

    #register new task
    Register-ScheduledTask -CimSession $c -TaskPath "\" -TaskName $task[3] -User "SYSTEM" -RunLevel Highest -Action $action -Trigger $trigger

}
```

error

```
Register-ScheduledTask : パラメーター 'Trigger' の引数変換を処理できません。値     "Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.Sched
uledJobTrigger" を型 "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance[]" に変換できません。エラー: "値 "Microsoft.Power
Shell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobTrigger" を型     "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance" に変換できません。エラー
: "無効な名前空間です ""
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:)[Register-ScheduledTask]、    ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Register-ScheduledTask
```

Please let me know if you need more information to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Please translate the error to English. Most likely you have an error in time conversion from string to `TimeSpan` or `DateTime`, whatever parameter is expected for "trigger".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use PowerShell remoting, because the commands for registering your tasks are performed in a remote session (and not via a CIM session from your local computer).

Example:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "hostname" -Credential (Get-Credential)

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

$tasks = @(("script1", "args1", "04:00:00", "name1"), ("script2", "args2", "04:30:00", "name2"))

foreach ($task in $tasks) {

    #setting action
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $task[0] -Argument $task[1] -WorkingDirectory "C:\unyo\script\"

    #setting trigger
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -at $task[2]

    #register new task
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" -TaskName $task[3] -User "SYSTEM" -RunLevel Highest -Action $action -Trigger $trigger

}
```

}

This [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx) describes how to enable remoting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I could do what I want! Thank you for your quick answer.